# Animate UITableViewCell gives me error

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableView`. I want to add a `cell` to the beginning of the `tableView` with animation. I tried the following:

```
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPath, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
```

But I get the following error:

> Cannot invoke `'reloadRowsAtIndexPaths'` with an argument list of type
>   `'(NSIndexPath!, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation)'`

(When I just do `tableView.reloadData()` it works fine.)

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the error, because `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` expects an array of index paths, not a single index path. However `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` wouldn't add a cell, but just reload the cells at the specified index paths.

Instead you should use `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` to add your cell.

Comment: Just curious. What's the diff of insertRowsAtIndexpath vs reloadData in this case? They both perform the same thing.

Comment: `reloadData` reloads all of your cells in the table view, `insertRowsAtIndexPath` just loads the new cell. Also the animation, you will get for `insertRowsAtIndexPath`, will properly fit your purpose better.

Answer (score 1):

`tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` expects an `[NSIndexPath]` instead of an `NSIndexPath!` as first argument.

so fix it by calling

```
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
let indexPaths = [indexPath]
tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
```